# Replacing an occurance according to what is following it?

Tags: php

```
 $data = "abcaooobooocooodoooeooofooogoooxyz";
```

**What I want to do ?**

I want to check each letter in the $data variable, if it preceds 'ooo' then I replace it with the same letter in upper case and remove the ooo otherwise just return the letter as it is

**For example when I call**

```
do_it($data);
```

**It must return the following**

```
abcABCDEFGxyz
```

**What I'm trying so far ?**

```
 function do_it($d) {
 $d = strtolower($d);
 $d = str_replace('aooo','A');
 $d = str_replace('booo','B');
 $d = str_replace('cooo','C');
 $d = str_replace('dooo','D');
 $d = str_replace('eooo','E');
 ... untill the end of alphabets
 return $d;
 }
```

**The question**

What is the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: by which way u tried so far ..?

Comment: The easiest is probably using [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression

```
preg_replace('/([\w]{1})ooo/e', 'strtoupper("$1")', $data);
```

Comment: Never mind, my comment is dead wrong. Sorry. (formerly: "can't execute arbitrary functions in `preg_replace` that way.")

Comment: You can actually, that's what the `e` modifier does. It applies an `eval` to the replacement strategy. It gives the correct answer, but `eval` is not very nice.

Comment: Confirmed, you can test it here: http://phptester.net/

Answer (score 0):

Using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

```
function replace($string) {
    return strtoupper(substr($string[0], 0, 1));
}
$text = "abcaooobooocooodoooeooofooogoooxyz";
echo preg_replace_callback("/[a-z]ooo/", "replace", $text);
// abcABCDEFGxyz
```